# Geolocation is not working in xamarin for iOS working fine in android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have created a application in xamarin for getting location and set it to map.The code is working fine for android platforms but not working in iOS.
The first time it shows the location on one activity but same code is not working on another activity in ios. I have also  added the location permission in .plist.

Following is my code

```
 public async void GetCurrentLocation()
    {
        try
        {

            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 0, true, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
            {
                ActivityType = Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
                AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
                DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                ListenForSignificantChanges = true,
                PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
            });
            count++;

            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += Current_PositionChanged;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    private void Current_PositionChanged(object sender, Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.PositionEventArgs e)
    {

            LatitudeLabel.Text =e.Position.Latitude.ToString();
            LongitudeLabel.Text = e.Position.Longitude.ToString();
            AltitudeLabel.Text = e.Position.Altitude.ToString();
}
```

I have added screen shots also 
First screen where lat long coming [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQIcg.png)
Second Screen where lat long not coming [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBdNh.png)